# Strange padding on right side of the screen when trying to align ImageView to right

Tags: android-layout

I set the ImageView's layout_gravity to "right" and tried to statically assign 0px padding to all four edges, but I still get the strange, about 10px "padding" to right side of screen. This problem occurs only in landscape orientation. In vertical orientation, the image scales correctly and no padding is happening.

The XML file looks like:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:padding="0px"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<SurfaceView
  android:id="@+id/surfaceview"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
/>

<ImageView 
  android:id="@+id/img1"
  android:src="@drawable/testimage"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_gravity="right"
/>    
</FrameLayout>
```

Image size is 720x405 and my devices screen is 800x480.